# I have written a recursive function but it only returns one child, how can I get this to return all children?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that represent the markup structure of a HTML page. I have written a recursive function that partially works but can not figure out how to return more than one child from an object that has more than one child.

Here is the array of objects:

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {"type": "Root", "id":0, "children" : [
    {"type" : "Title", "id": "foo"},
    {"type" : "Image", "id": "bar"},
    {"type" : "Container", "id": "blo", "children":[ 
      {"type" : "Container", "id": "goo", "children":[
        {"type" : "Image", "id": "tar"},
        {"type" : "Video", "id": "yar"}
      ]},
      {"type" : "Container", "id": "sha", "children":[ 
        {"type" : "Title", "id": "koo"},
      ]},
    ]},
    {"type" : "Container", "id": "boo", "children":[
      {"type" : "Container", "id": "bos", "children":[
        {"type" : "Container", "id": "ooo", "children":[
          {"type" : "Container", "id": "loo", "children":[
            {"type" : "Title", "id": "bar"},
            {"type" : "Image", "id": "rab"}
          ]}
        ]}
      ]}
    ]}
  ]}
 ]
```

Here is my code:

```
    const findChildren = (el) => {
      let x = []
      if(el.type === "Container"){
        x += '[' + el.type + ']' 
        + findChildren(el.children[0]) 
        + '[/' + el.type + ']'
        return x 
      }
      else{ 
       return x += '[' + el.type + '/]'
      }
    }

    genStructure = (data) => {
      let output = []
      data.forEach(function(el) {
        output += findChildren(el)
      });
      return output
    }

    genStructure(arrayOfObjects[0].children) // here I ignore root as it will always be the same
```

This is what I get when I run it.

```
[Title/][Image/][Container][Container][Image/][/Container][/Container][Container][Container][Container][Container][Title/][/Container][/Container][/Container][/Container]
```

But this is what I need when I run it. As you can see there is a missing container with a title in it (id of `sha` for the container and `koo` for the title) and there is a missing title (id of `rab`)

```
[Title/][Image/][Container][Container][Image/][Video/][/Container][Container][Title/][/Container][/Container][Container][Container][Container][Container][Title/][Image/][/Container][/Container][/Container][/Container]
```

I feel like I might be close but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. How can I get the missing data?

Here is a jsfiddle of it https://jsfiddle.net/gwxhymq4/5/

Comment: first of all, if `output` is an array, you can't append items to it using `+`. You'll need to use `output.push(/*...*/)`

Comment: @DanielCheung Technically, you *can* - the empty array will be coerced to a string, resulting in the empty string being concatenated with the expression on the right - but having an array in the first place doesn't make any sense, yeah.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, I understand. That's why I phrase it as "appending items". But same thought, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `+ findChildren(el.children[0])`, you should use `.map` to iterate over *all* children and get the resulting string (not just the first child):

```
+ el.children.map(findChildren).join('')
```

or call `genStructure` again, which uses the same logic.

Also, it would be more appropriate to either initialize `x` to the empty string, or leave it off entirely and just `return` the expressions inside the `if`/`else`:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {"type": "Root", "id":0, "children" : [
    {"type" : "Title", "id": "foo"},
    {"type" : "Image", "id": "bar"},
    {"type" : "Container", "id": "blo", "children":[ 
      {"type" : "Container", "id": "goo", "children":[
        {"type" : "Image", "id": "tar"},
        {"type" : "Video", "id": "yar"}
      ]},
      {"type" : "Container", "id": "sha", "children":[ 
        {"type" : "Title", "id": "koo"},
      ]},
    ]},
    {"type" : "Container", "id": "boo", "children":[
      {"type" : "Container", "id": "bos", "children":[
        {"type" : "Container", "id": "ooo", "children":[
          {"type" : "Container", "id": "loo", "children":[
            {"type" : "Title", "id": "bar"},
            {"type" : "Image", "id": "rab"}
          ]}
        ]}
      ]}
    ]}
  ]}
 ]
const findChildren = (el) => {
  if(el.type === "Container"){
    return (
      '[Container]' 
      + mapChildren(el)
      + '[/Container]'
    );
  } else{ 
   return '[' + el.type + '/]'
  }
};

const mapChildren = (element) => {
  return element.children.map(findChildren).join('');
}

console.log(mapChildren(arrayOfObjects[0]));
```

Comment: Instead of `el.children.map(findChildren).join('')`, I'd recommend to call `genStructure(el.children)`, which the OP has prepared for exactly that purpose. (Of course, its implementation should be fixed or simplified to what you have)

Answer (score 0):

```
const findChildren = (el) => {
  let x = '';
  if(el.type === "Container"){
    el.children.forEach(function(child) {
        x += findChildren(child)
    });
    return '[' + el.type + ']' + x + '[/' + el.type + ']';
  }
  else{ 
   return '[' + el.type + '/]'
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is HTML code.

```
<div id='meh'>

</div>
```

And This is JavaScript code.

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {"type": "Root", "id":0, "children" : [
    {"type" : "Title", "id": "foo"},
    {"type" : "Image", "id": "bar"},
    {"type" : "Container", "id": "blo", "children":[ 
      {"type" : "Container", "id": "goo", "children":[
        {"type" : "Image", "id": "tar"},
        {"type" : "Video", "id": "yar"}
      ]},
      {"type" : "Container", "id": "sha", "children":[ 
        {"type" : "Title", "id": "koo"},
      ]},
    ]},
    {"type" : "Container", "id": "boo", "children":[
      {"type" : "Container", "id": "bos", "children":[
        {"type" : "Container", "id": "ooo", "children":[
          {"type" : "Container", "id": "loo", "children":[
            {"type" : "Title", "id": "bar"},
            {"type" : "Image", "id": "rab"}
          ]}
        ]}
      ]}
    ] }
  ]}
]

const findChildren = (el) => {
        let x = []
        if(el.type === "Container"){

      x += '[' + el.type + ']';
      el.children.forEach(e => {
        x += findChildren(e)
      });
      x += '[/' + el.type + ']';
      return x 
        }
    else{ 
      return x += '[' + el.type + '/]'
    }
}
  
genStructure = (data) => {
  let output = []
  data.forEach(function(el) {
   output += findChildren(el)
});
  return output
}


const el = document.getElementById("meh")
el.innerHTML = genStructure(arrayOfObjects[0].children)
```

And this is the result.

```
[Title/][Image/][Container][Container][Image/][Video/][/Container][Container][Title/][/Container][/Container][Container][Container][Container][Container][Title/][Image/][/Container][/Container][/Container][/Container]
```